# FXM in Azure PaaS crashes when the JS files is accessed

Tags: fxm

I have a sitecore 8.2u7 as `PaaS` and when I try to load a js file in the browser , it shows an error and in the log I get this message

I checked in the configuration files for any parameter but I can't find anything

Anyone can say what is this ?

```
ERROR [Bundle]: Error running bundle pipeline - bundle.beacon
Exception: System.ArgumentException
Message: The URL '~d:\local\temp\beacon_47542.js' is not valid. Only application relative URLs (~/url) are allowed.
Parameter name: virtualPath
Source: System.Web.Optimization
   at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.Include(String virtualPath, IItemTransform[] transforms)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.CorePipelineWrapper.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.FXM.Bundling.BundleRegistrar.GenerateAndRegisterBundle(String bundleIdentifier, PipelineArgs args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the location of the Temp folder is in your `\Website` folder. use a relative path. For Sitecore 9 you can specify that in the `FXM.BundledJSFilesPath` setting in the `Sitecore.FXM.config` file.

Probably the same for Sitecore 8.2, Else take a look at your config files and search for `d:\local\temp` you can also use the `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` url to take a look at your config. See [FXM issues](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/10/p/8501/17283) looks like old Sitecore versions use this variable `<sc.variable name="tempFolder" value="/temp"/>`